Is the Principle of Maximum Entropy a Paradox?
Recently I have been learning about the Principle of Maximum Entropy (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_maximum_entropy) for estimating the distribution and parameters of a probability distribution based on some data.

Given some data $x_1, ..., x_n$, we are interested in estimating the probability distribution $P$ that might have generated this data.
We some constraints $f_j(X)$ for $j = 1, ..., m$. As I understand, these constraints are functions (e.g. perhaps the mean is non-negative).

The constraints can be written as:
$$E[f_j(X)] = \sum_{i=1}^{n} p_i f_j(x_i) = a_j$$
The entropy of the distribution $P$ is given by:
$$H(P) = -\sum_{i=1}^{n} p_i \log(p_i)$$
We want to find the distribution $P$ that maximizes this entropy subject to the constraints.
Lagrange Optimization can come in handy given that this is a Constrained Optimization problem. For this problem, the Lagrange can be written as:
$$L(P, \lambda) = -\sum_{i=1}^{n} p_i \log(p_i) + \sum_{j=1}^{m} \lambda_j (a_j - \sum_{i=1}^{n} p_i f_j(x_i))$$
Here, $\lambda = (\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_m)$ are the Lagrange multipliers.
As I understand, we want to find the $P$ and $\lambda$ that maximize this Lagrangian. This involves taking derivatives with respect to $p_i$ and $\lambda_j$, setting them equal to zero, and solving for $p_i$ and $\lambda_j$:
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial p_i} = -\log(p_i) - 1 - \sum_{j=1}^{m} \lambda_j f_j(x_i)$$
$$-\log(p_i) - 1 - \sum_{j=1}^{m} \lambda_j f_j(x_i) = 0$$
$$p_i = \exp\left(-1 - \sum_{j=1}^{m} \lambda_j f_j(x_i)\right)$$
The solution will give us the maximum entropy distribution $P$ and the parameters $\lambda$ that satisfy the constraints.
Based on this, I have the following question:

As I understand, high entropy = low stability, high disorder and high surprise.
If you want to estimate the distribution and the parameters of some distribution given some data.... wouldn't we want the distribution to have low entropy? i.e. high stability, low disorder and low surprise?
Thus, why is high entropy seen as ideal? Given some data, why would we want to find a distribution corresponding to maximum entropy instead of minimum entropy? Is this paradoxical?


Why do you think that high entropy corresponds to low stability? In a glass of water the H2O molecules move around a bit and bounce against each other. The entropy is high. The glass of water is perfectly stable.

@ M. Wind : Thank you for your reply! In this water example - I thought it the macro level entropy is stable, but the movement at the micro level is high?

I think you have your ideas the wrong way around.
For the given data, the maximum entropy distribution is generally the most stable one. You can sort of view the entropy as being the expectation of the log-likelihood of seeing the given data from any given distribution, and so maximising this value is finding the distribution that is most likely to give this particular result. As such, under typical circumstances it's going to be a nice stable maximum across the probability space.
It's also the least surprising distribution, in the sense that it's the one where you would be the least surprised to see the data you have. For example, consider the basic case of a weighted coin that I flipped 10 times. If 8 of the flips were heads, would you be more surprised if I told you that it was actually weighted to have a 20% chance of heads or a 80% chance?

@ ConMan: Thank you so much for your answer! I am still a bit confused ... but I will try to read more on this...

I think the distinction here is that 8/10 heads pointing to p(H) = 0.8 versus p(H) = 0.2 is more the concept of maximum likelihood. -- So the question would then be why would you attempt to maximize entropy if you already have maximum likelihood. Especially since maximum entropy in this case would likely point to p(H) = 0.5.
